# Interpreting MeanDecreaseGini graph in R

Tags: random-forest, importance, gini

Using the `randomForest` package in R, I fitted a customer churn dataset to a random forest model. The first objective was to identify the most important variables in my dataset.

Using the `varImpPlot` function, I got a graph that looks like this.

What is the best way to interpret these results?
Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The meanDecreaseGini means exactly that: The average decrease in Gini impurity over all splits using the respective variable.